# UITableViewController and prefetching

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous, prefetch

In my older Swift 3 app I have been using a UITableView and I implemented the function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath])
```

Now I redesign the app and would like to use a UITableViewController instead and cant find a similar function to prefetch. Is there a similar function for the TableViewController?

I am using the table to show async downloaded images and pdf:s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply have your controller adopt the `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching` protocol. The function will then be available (**and** required).

As you point out in your comment, you also have to set the `prefetchDataSource` of the table view.

Comment: Thanks, earlier I had test that with no success but with your answer I tested it again and now I saw that I have forgot to set tableView.prefetchDataSource = self (which I probably first I thought I did not need beacause of the tableviewcontroller). Thanks.